# Java.util.PropertyPermission Failure

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I'm trying to run a simple Java Web Start App.  I wrote my code in `NetBeans` and used the `jar` exported for my `.jnlp` file.  Eventually I plan on having the code read from the windows registry and use that data, but for now all I'm doing is creating a `String` then calling `System.out.println(strName);` I am self signing the jar using the strategy outlined [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/web-start/java-web-start-getting-started/).  When I download and run the `.jnlp`, I get the following exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jna.debug_load" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JavaWebStartSecurity.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:95)
    at com.sun.jna.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:41)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg$HKEY.<init>(WinReg.java:32)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.<clinit>(WinReg.java:61)
    at cvbxtractor.CvbXtractor.main(CvbXtractor.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried adding `permission java.util.PropertyPermission "jna.debug_load", "read";` to my `java.policy` file, I have tried signing and resigning any `jars` it might be using, and made sure my `.jnlp` has the

```
 <security>
      <all-permissions/>
 </security>
```

line in it, but none have helped.  I'm sure I'm just missing some security toggle somewhere, if this is easy please forgive me, this is my first Java Web Start App.

Comment: Does the manifest.mf declare all-permissions?

Answer (score 2):

As of java 7u45, you can't read system properties when running from a jnlp. Oracle basically ruined `javaws`. If you're writing a new app, I would recommend staying away from java webstart. It's broken and they just keep making it worse by forcing security updates that break your application.

That being said, one partial workaround to this problem is to prefix all of your properties with `jnlp.`. So, you'd have to rename your property `jnlp.jna.debug_load`. If it's a property from a third party library/jar you're using, you're out of luck.